# Trying to remove a file and its parent directories

Tags: bash, rm

I've got a script that finds files within folders older than 30 days:

```
find /my/path/*/README.txt -mtime +30
```

that'll then produce a result such as

```
/my/path/jobs1/README.txt
/my/path/job2/README.txt
/my/path/job3/README.txt
```

Now the part I'm stuck at is I'd like to remove the folder + files that are older than 30 days.

```
 find /my/path/*/README.txt -mtime +30 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

doesn't seem to work. It's only removing the readme.txt file

so ideally I'd like to just remove /job1, /job2, /job3 and any nested files

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Do you want to remove every file in a folder that contains a file older than 30 days, or just the files that are older than 30 days (leaving the directory if it still contains newer files)?

Comment: an approach could have been : find ... -depth -print, and first delete (rm) files older than 30 days under /my/path/, then do it again to delete (rmdir) the remaining /my/path/.../directories/ older than 30 days... (-depth starting with "leafs" in the directory tree) but, having deleted a file in it, they are now a few seconds old ^^. So you'll need to script it in a few steps, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a safer way:

```
find /my/path/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'README.txt' -mtime +30 -printf '%h\n' | xargs echo rm -r
```

Remove `echo` if you find it  already correct after seeing the output.

With that you use `printf '%h\n'` to get the directory of the file, then use `xargs` to process it.

Comment: This will delete the directory containing the file, even if this directory (and subdirs) contains other files more recent or older... It can be quite dangerous, depending on /my/path/.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the following command in order to recursively remove directories modified more than 30 days ago.

```
find /my/path/ -type d -mtime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: ... and probably wipe out very important directories in the process ^^  do NOT try in "/", as any directories without modification (ie, without files added/removed/changed in it) will be deleted, including any of its subdirs and files. For example there is a good chance that /lib can be older than 30 days...

Comment: Who said anything about running it in "/"?

Comment: noone, and especially not you, I know. But I am worried someone reading, without knowing all the implications, may try it on sensitive paths. That was just a warning for them.